# Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $f(m,n) = 36^m - 5^n$. When is $\min |f(m,n)|$ attained?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is inspired from the following problem.

***Problem***

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $f(m,n) = 36^m - 5^n$. Find the smallest value of $|f(m,n)|$.

I was able to prove that $f(1,2) = 11$ is the smallest value of $|f(m,n)|$. (The solution is outlined below).

My question is how to investigate whether $(m,n) = (1,2)$ is the only integer solution to $|f(m,n)| = 11$?

***Solution to Original Problem***

Since $f(1,2) = 11$, we must have $\min |f(m,n)| \leq 11$.

It is obvious that $f(m,n) \neq 0 \; \; \forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

The unit's digit of $f(m,n)$ can either be $1$ (iff $36^m > 5^n$) or $9$ (iff $5^n > 36^m$).

If unit's digit is $1$, then $\min |f(m,n)| < 11 \implies 36^m - 5^n = 1 \implies 36^m - 1 = 5^n \implies 35| 5^n \implies 7| 5^n$ which is a contradiction. (Third implication in the chain follows from the fact that $35 | (36^m - 1) \; \; \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$).

If unit's digit is 9, then $\min |f(m,n)| < 11 \implies 5^n - 36^m = 9 \implies 5^n = 36^m + 9 \implies 9 | 5^n$ which is again a contradiction.

Hence $\min |f(m,n)| = 11$.

The question I have been unable to answer is whether $m = 1, n = 2$ is the only pair of values at which the minimum is attained.

Any and all thoughts appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks! Will do the edit.

Comment: $ 0 \in \mathbb N$, then you should precise that you want $m$ and $n$ non zero, because $f(0,0)=0$

Comment: Not all conventions place $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @fonfonx Thanks! Will write $\mathbb{Z}^+$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$, which I always imagined to include all positive integers.

Comment: Mod $3$, the equation $36^m-5^n=11$ implies $n$ is even. So you have to solve $36^m-25^k=11$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @alex.jordan comment, since $n$ is even, you have to solve
$$(6^m)^2-(5^k)^2=11$$

This leads to $(6^m-5^k)\cdot(6^m+5^k)=11$. If $m$ or $k$ is greater than 1, $6^m+5^k > 11$. Therefore the product cannot be equal to 11 if either $m$ or $k$ is greater than 1.